# Trying to convert string to datetime using ParseExact

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to convert a string like this `'5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM'` to a `datetime` for use as a PowerShell object but I am getting an error

I am trying to use the `[datetime]::ParseExact` method

```
$Date = "5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM"

[datetime]::ParseExact($Date,'MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
```

Instead of getting a datetime object, I just get this error:

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to include the AM/PM code [`tt`] AND to switch from `HH` 24 hour format to `hh` 12 hour format AND to use the same delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PS /Users/js> [DateTime]'5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM'

Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM


PS /Users/js> ([DateTime]'5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM').gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Answer (score 3):

[postanote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) contains effective solutions, but it's worth analyzing the problem.

Firstly, **simply casting your string to `[datetime]` is enough**, because your input string is directly recognized according to the rules of the ***invariant* culture** that PowerShell applies in this case, irrespective of the *current* culture (the invariant culture is meant to be culture-neutral and is based on the US-English culture):

```
PS> [datetime] "5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM"

Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM
```

Behind the scenes, PowerShell translates this into the following call:

```
[datetime]::Parse("5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

By contrast, `Get-Date` *is* sensitive to the *current* culture:

```
# Works, but only in cultures that use AM / PM and place the month *first* in
# dates, notably, US-English.
PS> Get-Date -Date "5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM"

Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM
```

The above would fail in cultures such as `fr-FR` (French (France)), where it is the *day* that comes first.

This **unfortunate discrepancy in data-type-conversion behavior between casts and cmdlet parameters** is a longstanding bug documented [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989); for backward-compatibility reasons, however, it won't be fixed.

---

As for **what you tried**:

As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out, **your problem is that that your format string, `'MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss'` doesn't match the input date string, `"5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM"`**:

- `HH` represents the hour of the day in 24-hour format, whereas your input uses 12-hour format.
- The `PM` in your input is not represented in the format string; use `tt` to generically represent the AM / PM specifier.
- You're using spaces to separate the date components, whereas the input string uses `/`
- Your format string specifies a *double*-digit month component (`MM`; e.g., `05`), whereas the input has only a single digit (`5`).

Therefore, you should have used the following:

```
PS> [datetime]::ParseExact('5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM','M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM
```

Note the use of `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` instead of `$null`, as the latter would default to the *current* culture, which means that call may fail in cultures that use localized AM / PM designators (for instance, in the Vietnamese culture (`vi-VN`), the designators are `SA` / `CH`).

Of course, you could have used an appropriate specific culture such as `en-US` (English (United States)) as well (or assume that your code will never run with any other culture active).

---

As an aside, note that **even `/` and `:` in format strings aren't *literals*: they represent the culture-specific date and time separators**, respectively.

To treat them as literals, you'd have to use *embedded quoting*; e.g., `/` would be quoted as `'/'`, `'"/"` or `\/`

To demonstrate the non-literal interpretation:

```
PS> [datetime]::ParseExact('6.2019','M/yyyy', [cultureinfo] 'de-DE')

Saturday, June 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Note how `/` matched the culture-appropriate date separator, `.`.

While the culture-appropriate separators are always used on *output* formatting, during *parsing* - as a courtesy -  the *literal* interpretation of `/` and `:` is used as a *fallback* mechanism:

```
# Works too - "/" is also recognized as a literal.
PS> [datetime]::ParseExact('6/2019','M/yyyy', [cultureinfo] 'de-DE')

Saturday, June 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these.

```
($stringToDatetime1 = '5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM' | Get-Date)
Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM

($stringToDatetime2 = [DateTime]::ParseExact('5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM','M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt',$null))
Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM

($stringToDatetime3 = [Datetime]'5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM')
Wednesday, May 29, 2019 8:46:47 PM
```

BTW, this error is fully documented here:

[PowerShell [DateTime] throws the error “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.”](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dsheehan/2017/09/24/powershell-datetime-throws-the-error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

Comment: Thanks all - ($stringToDatetime2 = [DateTime]::ParseExact('5/29/2019 8:46:47 PM','M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt',$null)) worked for me. And I get it now.